# Check the state of RDS

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I have the following script:

```
aws rds start-db-instance --db-instance-identifier uat-db-up --profile=UAT
STATE="$(aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier db-identifier | jq --raw-output '.DBInstances | .[].DBInstanceStatus')"
while ["$STATE" != "available"]
do
    sleep 2m
done
```

I need to check when STATE is going to be in available after the RDS starts, but in this way I am not sure that is going to execute

```
STATE="$(aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier db-identifier | jq --raw-output '.DBInstances | .[].DBInstanceStatus')"
```

everytime before while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you would use [db-instance-available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/wait/db-instance-available.html) waiter:

```
aws rds wait db-instance-available --db-instance-identifier <db-id>
```

Comment: If I use the command you give, this will replace the while loop, is that what you meant

Comment: Thank you very much, I think that is the best option after reading the documentation

Comment: @PetyaPetkova No problem. If you want to access, have to press a "tick" symbol under upvote/downvote buttons.